# contrast error factors with 2 or more levels

Tags: r, variables, factors

I'm doing a bootstrap on R for a multivariate regression: I have variables that cause problems because they are less than one level, I tried to solve this with the function as factor.

> Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) :
> contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

How can i solve this?

Comment: If they only have one level, what are they doing in your model? Why not just get rid of them?

Comment: @AllanCameron: it's worse than that: they have _less than_ one level.  So, perhaps they are missing.  To OP: it is logically impossible to form a contrast _within_ a factor having only one level.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am new to R. Thank you for your answer, and I apologize for the trouble. I have variables with levels and I'm encountering an error despite using the following code. Can you please help me?

I appreciate your assistance!

Comment: somme Variables:

    Variable rand has levels: A, B
   
    Variable ind_rocu has levels: 0, 1
    Variable ind_autr has levels: 0, 1
   
    Variable hypno_interv has levels: 0, NA
   
  
    Variable hypotens_interv has levels: 0, 1
    Variable hypox_interv has levels: 1, 0
    Variable anemo_interv has levels: Non, Oui, NA, ND
    Variable metha_induction has levels: 1, 0, NA
    Variable opio_interv has levels: Non, Oui, NA
    Variable anest_loc has levels: Non, Oui, NA
    Variable anest_med has levels: Non, Oui, ND, NA

Comment: VARS90 <- list()
FORMS90 <- list()

for (.m in seq(30)) {
  .dm <- complete(dm1, .m)
  for (.i in seq(20)) {
    .d <- .dm %>% sample_frac(1, replace = TRUE)

Comment: .fit <- try(step(glm(formula = cp_90_def ~ rand + duree_interv + eva0 + duree_interv + int_antalg + ind_curar + ind_celoc + ind_hypno + ind_metha + ind_opio + ind_prop + ind_rocu + ind_autr + ind_autr_cur + keta_ind_antal + inter_opio + seda_inter + prop_inter + hypno_interv + halo_interv + corti_interv + even_interv + saigne_interv + hypotens_interv + hypox_interv + anemo_interv + metha_induction + duree_anest + opio_interv + antaldose_interv + antal_interv + anest_loc + anest_med, data = .d), k = log(nrow(.d)), trace = FALSE))

Comment: if (!"try-error" %in% class(.fit)) {
      VARS90 <- c(VARS90, list(names(.fit$coefficients)[-1]))
      FORMS90 <- c(FORMS90, .fit$formula[[3]])
    }
  }
}

I appreciate your assistance!